# How to change preview of the dragged image size only dragging in angular material drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a image inside the Div element.Then I have set the **cdkdrag** for **img** element. I only wanted to move image not div that is the reason I put cdkdrag for image tag.

But now the problem is If I go to change the Width and height of the **.cdk-drag-preview** class I can see image is small when dragging but when I move that image mouse pointer is not on the image it is beside the image. why is that happen how to fix that problem.

Image should be one size before dragging but when I start to drag it should be small.

```
.cdk-drag-preview {
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
}
```

Here is my jsFiddle : [fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bgfugg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store in a variable the offset when mousedown and use cdkDragMoved in the way

```
  offset:any=null

  setStyle(event: MouseEvent) {
    const rect = (event.target as HTMLElement).getBoundingClientRect();
    this.offset={x:event.offsetX*50/rect.width,y:event.offsetY*50/rect.height };
  }
  public onDragMove(event: CdkDragMove<any>): void {
    const el=(document.getElementsByClassName('cdk-drag-preview')[0])as any
    const xPos = event.pointerPosition.x - this.offset.x;
    const yPos = event.pointerPosition.y - this.offset.y;
    el.style.transform = `translate3d(${xPos}px, ${yPos}px, 0)`;
  }
```

the .html

```
<div class="dragItem"  >
  <img cdkDrag  src="..."
       (mousedown)="setStyle($event)" 
       (cdkDragMoved)="onDragMove($event)"
  />
</div>
```

NOTE: See that I remove de cdkDrag from outer div

Comment: only one problem is when I set boundry image is overfllow the boundy area

Answer (score 0):

use cdkDragPreview element to set the width and height properties inside it. This will create a new element that only appears during dragging and does not affect the size of the original element.

```
<div class="container">
  <div cdkDragBoundary>
    <!-- Original -->
    <img cdkDrag src="image.jpg">
    <div class="item">Item to drag</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Preview -->
  <div cdkDragPreview>
    <img src="image.jpg" class="preview-image">
  </div>
</div>
```

adjust the styles as per your needs:

```
.cdk-drag-preview {
  /* No need width or height */
}

.cdkDragPreview .preview-image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

now preview element with the smaller image size while dragging, but the orig. element stays the same size.