# Angular CDK Drag element displaced if parent has translate3d

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm using `"@angular/cdk": "^15.2.4"` and having difficulties figuring out how to resolve the problem in the title.
That is, I have some parent DOM element coming from an external library that gets a `transform: translate3d();` applied, and I have some draggable elements inside that element using CDK's dragdrop feature. When start dragging, the drag helper element gets a `position: fixed !important` style, its top and left properties are set to 0, and its dragging position is applied via `transform: translate3d()` as well.

The problem is, due to the `translate3d` on the parent element, the draggable's `position: fixed` causes the containing block for the dragging element will be that particular parent, instead of the whole HTML element, which I think is the base of calculations for the `translate3d()` operation on the draggable element.
It seems like CDK's drag does not consider if there's a parent element with a transform property set, which results in wrong numbers being calculated for transformation.
Does anyone have an idea how could I overcome this?

I was trying to set `transform:none` and playing around with `position`s but no luck so far. I can think of a JS solution of recalculating the translate values manually, but I'd be curious if there's a simpler way to do this.

Comment: As idea (really I don't know if work), you can try to get in mousedown the "transform" and store in a variable the "offset" position and the "dimensions". In onDragMove you add the offset position like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73766218/how-to-change-preview-of-the-dragged-image-size-only-dragging-in-angular-materia/73769520#73769520).

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of using `cdkDragConstrainPosition` input of [CDKDrag directive](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag) for something similar, but this feels overly complicated for such a simple-looking problem...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I ended up transforming the `transform` style to top+left for the ancestor element.

In details, before dragging, I extracted the transformation matrix into an array of numbers by splitting up the transform string, and used the last 2 values to set `top` and `left` values. After dragging is finished, I write back the original `transform` style based on the previous `top` and `left` values.

Code to get offset values:

```
const getOffsetFromTransform = (element) => {
  const originalTransform = getComputedStyle(element).transform;
  const transformMatch = originalTransform.match(/^matrix3d\((.+)\)$/);

  // Extract the translation values from the transform matrix
  const matrixValues = transformMatch[1].split(',').map(parseFloat);
  const offsetX = matrixValues[12];
  const offsetY = matrixValues[13];

  return {offsetX, offsetY};
}
```